# Can i use exactly same entity for two tables JPA HIBERNATE

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, entity

I have a rare scenario where i have to maintain two tables say
Student_failed and Student_passed. both have exactly same schema.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "student_failed")
    public class StudentFailed {
        @Id
        @Column(name="id")
        private String id;
        
        @Column(name="student_name")
        private String studentName;
        
        @Column(name="home_town")
        private String homeTown;
    
    ...
    
    
    }



and 

@Entity
@Table(name = "student_passed")
public class StudentPassed {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id;
    
    @Column(name="student_name")
    private String studentName;
    
    @Column(name="home_town")
    private String homeTown;

...


}
```

as both entities are same i want to use single entity for both table. I have two different controllers that do crud operations on either of the tables.

Can i use single entity and map it to both the tables? I came across @SecondaryTables annotation but i am not sure it if will work.

PS: i know its a bad approach to keep two different tables with same fields but due to some specific requirement i am not allowed to do that).

Comment: It's really bad approach to maintain single enitity for two table or same fields of two table if they originally related(Like your  ex)

Comment: @Rono: the thing is we have two different clients and for them we have to keep separate  table that is shared with them.

Comment: Want to share data in UI or access of database table ?

Comment: @Rono: i want to do crud operation on both the tables

Comment: You can make a flag column in table and use same table for both client

Comment: @Rono: there are business reasons that we need it separately. is there any way we can do it keeping both tables different?

Comment: Maybe not possible.